Último registro según fecha, por usuario, con MySQL
Lo que intento es, de una tabla de información, regresar todos los últimos registros según fecha, pero solo mostrar el último de los diferentes usuarios.
Si tengo 5 usuarios = idcontrol (1,2,3,4,5) requiero los últimos registros según fecha de cada uno (la fecha más actual me tiene que mostrar su movimiento).
En esta consulta mi detalle es que no me muestra la descripción ni la última fecha: me da fechas atrasadas, no la más actual...
SELECT `fecha`, `descripcion`, DATEDIFF(NOW(), `fecha`) AS `dias`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `idcontrol` ORDER BY `fecha` DESC) `idcontrol`
FROM `bitacora`
GROUP BY `idcontrol`
ORDER BY `fecha` DESC;

Y esta consulta me funciona pero pues tengo que estar indicando cada idcontrol para los distintos valores:
SELECT `fecha`, `descripcion`, `idcontrol` FROM `bitacora` WHERE `idcontrol` = '321'
ORDER BY `fecha` DESC
LIMIT 1

Requiero una que me muestre todos los idcontrol de la fecha más cercana.
Asi es mi tabla ya esta relacionada pero no requiero ninguna dato de otra tabla mas que de ella misma
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `bitacora` (
  `fecha` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `accion` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_spanish_ci' NOT NULL,
  `MySQL` MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_spanish_ci' NOT NULL,
  `recupera` MEDIUMTEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_spanish_ci' NULL,
  `idusuario` VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_spanish_ci' NOT NULL,
  `idcontrol` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`fecha`),
  INDEX `fk_bitacora_usuario1_idx` (`idusuario` ASC, `idcontrol` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_bitacora_usuario1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idusuario` , `idcontrol`)
    REFERENCES `usuario` (`idusuario` , `idcontrol`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
COMMENT = ' ';


Modifiqué el título porque parece ser que eso es lo que estás buscando. ¿Por qué en la primera consulta estás haciendo la agrupación por idcontrol en lugar de por usuario? ¿O la columna usuario no existe?

Veo una falla fundamental en tu tabla en cuanto al idcontrol vs el idusuario.
El idcontrol debería ser el id único de la tabla bitacora, ya sabes, el que lleva la cuenta de los registros como tal. (1,2,3...etc)
Por otro lado, el idusuario, debería ser el registro con el cuál relacionarás la tabla, con dicho usuario. Por ejemplo: "El usuario 3, realizó el registro 7 y 10".
Teniendo esto en cuenta, créo que deberías modificar o tu tabla, o considerar el hecho de que exista una tabla de usuarios además de la de bitácora.
Con eso abordado, podemos proseguir de la siguiente manera: Añadiremos el idusuario como columna a la tabla, para poder realizar la comparación.
-- Consultamos los datos de la tabla bitacora, considerando el idusuario
SELECT b1.idcontrol, b1.fecha, b1.descripcion, b1.idusuario
FROM bitacora AS b1
-- Subconsulta para obtener la fecha más reciente (MAX_FECHA) por idusuario
JOIN (
    SELECT idusuario, MAX(fecha) AS max_fecha
    FROM bitacora
    GROUP BY idusuario
) b2
-- Unimos ambas consultas usando los datos a comparar
ON b1.idusuario = b2.idusuario AND b1.fecha = b2.max_fecha
-- Ordenamos por el idusuario o el dato que necesites
ORDER BY b1.idusuario

Y bajo una tabla de pruebas, logro obtener con esto, lo siguiente:
Vale destacar que los registros, van del 1 al 25, y las fechas desde el dia 01 al 05. Por lo que efectivamente, estamos capturando el registro más actual, de cada usuario.


Realicé la consulta guiándome en el ejemplo de Excorpion y lo solucioné.
-- Consultamos los datos de la tabla bitacora, considerando el campo requerido
SELECT `t1`.`fecha`, `t1`.`descripcion`, `t1`.`idcontrol`
FROM `bitacora` `t1`
-- Subconsulta para obtener la fecha más reciente (MAX_FECHA) por campo
JOIN 
( SELECT `idcontrol`, MAX(`fecha`) AS `max_fecha`
    FROM `bitacora`
    GROUP BY `idcontrol`
 ) `t2` 
-- Unimos ambas consultas usando los datos a comparar
 ON `t1`.`idcontrol` = `t2`.`idcontrol` AND `t1`.`fecha` = `t2`.`max_fecha`
-- Ordenamos por el campo o el dato que necesites
ORDER BY `t1`.`fecha`

